# Understanding Composition and Aggregation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oop, c++-cli, aggregation, composition

How can I identify Composition and Aggregation in code? specially when drawing class diagrams for existing code?

I know Composition is a 'HAS-A' relationship and aggregation is a 'PART OF' relationship. And I know in composition subclass instance will get destroyed with the class and in aggregation it is not.

Following is a C++/CLI code

**Alarm.h**

```
ref class Alarm
{
   public:
       Notification ^n;
       Alarm();
};
```

**Alarm.cpp**

```
Alarm::Alarm()
{
     n = gcnew Notification ();
}
```

According to my knowledge, the connection between `Alarm` and `Notification` is Composition, because without `Alarm`, there is no `Notification`. Am I correct? If I am correct, how can I make this code to have an aggregation relationship between two classes? Code example there please?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I think aggregation is when the aggregated object is somehow exposed directly (and the user is expected to access it), while composition would be entirely internal and independent of what the user code sees.

Which would make your example an aggregation.